# Generating all possible 3-connected graphs

Tags: python, algorithm, graph, graph-theory, igraph

There is a conjecture by Tutte and Thomassen (Planarity and duality of finite and infinite graphs, 1979) saying this

> A 3-connected graph can be obtained
>   from a wheel by succestively adding an
>   edge and splitting a vertex into two
>   adjacent vertices of degree at least
>   three such that the edge joining them
>   is not contained in a 3-cycle. If we
>   apply a more general splitting
>   operation (i.e., we allow the edge
>   joining the two new vertices to be
>   contained in a 3-cycle) then we can
>   start out with K_4, and we need only
>   the splitting operation in order to
>   generate all 3-connected graphs.

I am trying to implement the last stated operation using iGraph with Python.

I want to define a function splitVertex(g,v), taking a graph g and a vertex v, and then have it split v in all the possible ways as the operation defines. Then I want a list of all these new graphs, and I will do some further work on them.

At this point, I have the following function creating two new vertices x and y, which would be the newly created vertices after the split.

```
def splitVertex(g,v):
    numver = g.vcount()

    g.add_vertices(2)

   x = numver
    y = numver+1

    g.add_edges([(x,y)])
```

Can somebody please help me out with a nice way to implement this? I know this will generate a massive amount of data, but that is alright, I have plenty of time ;)

Edit: Of course this have to be controlled in some way since the number of 3-connected graphs is infinite, but that is not what this question concerns.

Comment: You sound like you think the number of 3-connected graphs is finite, but it's not, so you can't generate *all*. Proof: Take two 3-connected graphs, add 3 suitable edges between them and you have a new 3-connected graph. Repeat ad infinum.

Comment: @THC4k: well, yes; but for a given 3-connected graph with n nodes, how to generate all 3-connected n+1-node descendants? I've been sketching it out on paper, and I'm scratching my head a bit too!

Comment: I do not think the number of 3-connected graphs is finite, but the number of 3-connected graphs on n vertices is definitely finite.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on [Keith's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4532406/generating-all-possible-3-connected-graphs/4535493#4535493). This is totally untested, but I guess the general idea is OK. This version generates the splits instead of returning all of them at once.

```
from itertools import chain, combinations

def powerset(iterable):
    "Returns all the possible subsets of the elements in a given iterable"
    s = list(iterable)
    return chain.from_iterable(combinations(s, r) for r in range(len(s)+1))

def partition(iterable):
    "Returns all the possible ways to partition a set into two subsets"
    s = set(iterable)
    for s1 in powerset(s):
        yield s1, s-s1

def split_vertex(graph, v1):
    # Note that you only need one extra vertex, you can use v for the other
    v2 = graph.vcount()
    graph.add_vertices(1)

    # Find the neighbors of v1
    neis = set(graph.neighbors(v1))

    # Delete all the edges incident on v1 - some of them will be re-added
    g.delete_edges(g.incident(v1))

    # Iterate over the powerset of neis to find all possible splits
    for set1, set2 in partition(neis):
        if len(set1) < 2 or len(set2) < 2:
            continue

        # Copy the original graph
        g2 = g.copy()

        # Add edges between v1 and members of set1
        g2.add_edges([(v1, v3) for v3 in set1])

        # Add edges between v2 and members of set2
        g2.add_edges([(v2, v3) for v3 in set2])

        # Return the result
        yield g2
```

Comment: Is this able to generate a wheel graph on 5 vertices from K_4? K_4 is a cubic graph, number of neighbors is always 3, partition in this case will always result in some set being less than 2, which will cause function to not return anything.

Answer (score 1):

Your splitting operation should be a bit more involved.  You need to modify all the edges that used to connect to `v` to connect to `x` or `y` instead.

```
def splitVertex(g,v):
  numver = g.vcount()
  g.add_vertices(2)
  x = numver
  y = numver+1
  g.add_edges([(x,y)])

  neighbors = g.neighbors(v)
  g.delete_vertices([v])

  new_graphs = []
  for (neighbors_of_x, neighbors_of_y) in set_split(neighbors):
    if len(neighbors_of_x) < 2: continue
    if len(neighbors_of_y) < 2: continue
    g2 = g.copy()
    g2.add_edges(map(lambda neighbor_of_x: [neighbor_of_x, x], neighbors_of_x))
    g2.add_edges(map(lambda neighbor_of_y: [neighbor_of_y, y], neighbors_of_y))
    new_graphs.add(g2)
  return new_graphs
```

Where `set_split` should generate all possible ways of splitting `neighbors` into two sets.

You then need to generate all possible choices for `v` and apply them to each graph.

You will likely get lots of isomorphic graphs.  I imagine there is a better way to do all of this, can't think of it off the top of my head.